# Running a webcam with built-in mic in Skype - Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam, microphone

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, While using Skype it will happily pickup my webcam feed, but can't seem to get the mic working. In Skype's audio settings I only get one option, which is "pulse audio" seems to be no option for it to use the web cams built in mic.

Any ideas how I can get it to work?

The Webcam is a Logitech HD Webcam C510.

Thanks in advance.

Also, In my pulse audio settings the webcam mic is shown there and seems to be working fine.

Just not through skype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have a C510 and it's a composite device of two: a camera and an audio device with just a mono input. This means that it's just a sound card like any other, and you need to control it using the audio mixer settings. For example, use `pavucontrol`:

[image]

Make sure it's unmuted and selected as input for the application (also unmute there):

[image]

And finally, check the audio mode, to be on Analogue Input:

[image]

It's working for me in Skype 4.1 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Device: `ID 046d:081d Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C510`

Comment: It seems you are using KDE. Is this solution also works for Unity?

Comment: @tuxtu Yes, pavucontrol and Pulseaudio in general works the same in any Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 1):

I use a logitech and microsoft hd cam. To get them to work I had to select them in the sound settings.

Right-click on the sound icon in the system tray

then select sound settings

Click the input tab and try to select the microphone for your camera.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a box automatically checked in Skype that states something like, "Allow Skype to control the volume." It's checked by default. Uncheck it and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Opening pavucontrol my micro was not working

1. Open alsamixer in a terminal
2. F5 to get all entries [image]
3. F6 to select sound card [image]
4. pop up the volume with up arrow and space bar to unmute it
5. Got it working on pavucontrol! [image]